# Cant edit Combobox DropDownStyle property

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, wpf-controls

I'm using Visual Studio and made a combobox using the graphic editor. I wanted to set its dropdownstyle property to simple but whenever I write
myCombobox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.Simple;
it says system.windows.controls.combobox doesn't contain any definition of this.

I suppose it's just a namespace problem or something basic, but I'm pretty new to programming (basically I'm searching through tutorials to get a little program done) and can't get a grasp on it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're confusing the Windows Forms control[`System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the WPF control [`System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :)

Answer (score 1):

The WPF `ComboBox` control (found in the `System.Windows.Controls` namespace) doesn't have a `DropDownStyle` property. You're confusing your WPF control for the *Windows Forms* ComboBox control, which can be found from the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.

If you want to make your WPF ComboBox look like it would be a WinForms ComboBox with ComboBoxStyle.Simple, set its `IsEditable` and `IsReadOnly` property to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using designer to set this value. In designer (graphic editor) click on your combo press alt+enter and properties windows should appear. Change the value of DropDownStyle  and save.

This way you visual studio will auto generate needed code in .designer.cs file of your user control or form.